# Production docker for ASP.NET application

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a plan to create a docker for use in production and docker and I want to have as few as possible security issue from trivy.

I want to use dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine as the base image, so now my question is that do I need to update the image as well?

```
FROM dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade --update && \
    apk add --update curl
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your question. What is it that your after? All you've done is what looks like the start of a Dockerfile. You've added the base image, you need to install the packages you want so your app can run

Comment: @ViaTech, yes you are right, so what is expected is that other developer will create their image from my image.

Comment: @ViaTech: i found my answer, it seems that alpine images contain the latest fixes, security patches and etc. and we don't need to update them as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bitnami or wolfi images, they are security focused.

**Update**:
These are the results for me on right now with trivy. (This might change any time in the future if a new CVE is revealed and registered in the CVE databases)

.net 6

1. bitnami/dotnet-sdk:6.0.413-debian-11-r24 (crit: 1, high: 23, medium: 5, all: 29)
2. mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.413-bullseye-slim-arm64v8 (crit: 1, high: 23, medium: 5, all: 29)

.net 7

1. cgr.dev/chainguard/dotnet-sdk:latest (crit: 0, high: 15, medium: 0,all: 15)
2. bitnami/dotnet-sdk:7.0.400-debian-11-r24 (crit: 1, high: 5, medium: 6, all:  12)
3. mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.400-bullseye-slim-arm64v8 (crit: 1, high: 5, medium: 6, all: 12)

While the chainguard/wolfi images has 0 critical, it has more high than the others. Bitnami and microsoft slim images looks the same.

However your concern shouldn't be the dotnet-sdk image but the dotnet-runtime because that is what you should ship in your image that should be created with multistage build (build the app with the sdk in the first stage and copy the artifact into the second stage that is based on only the dotnet-runtime).

Also you can create your own minimalistic image literally from scratch, in Dockerfile you start with:

```
FROM scratch
```

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/base-images/

https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch

Comment: they were worse than the orginal image!!!
bitnami/dotnet-sdk:latest (debian 11.7)
Total: 538 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 411, MEDIUM: 70, HIGH: 53, CRITICAL: 4)

Comment: Can you recheck the chainguard image? I see 0 CVEs with trivy.

Comment: @AdrianMouat With chainguard you can use only the "latest" running tag for free, so the image under cgr.dev/chainguard/dotnet-sdk:latest is newer and updated compared to that I ran trivy against. If you want to use pinned versions/tags with chainguard images you need to use their paid plan (and you definitely want to pin image versions in prod). So yes, it is updated since then so it probably has less CVE-s today.